# How can I import a specific font into R and use it in ggplot graphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, extrafont

I'm trying to set the font of all my text in all my graphs to be Tenorite. I have it installed in my laptop in

```
C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\FontCache\4\CloudFonts
```

It's also easy to download from the internet. I'm trying to load the font using **extrafont** and then setting the base_family in the set_theme() command.

Here is what I'm doing. I'm running R version 4.2.2.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

font_import(paths = [mypath])
```

This seems to work fine. At this point the output is

> Scanning ttf files in [mypath] ...
> Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
> [mypath]\26512206606.ttf : Tenorite-BoldItalic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
> [mypath]\26622973498.ttf : Tenorite-Italic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
> [mypath]\27733932592.ttf : Tenorite-Bold already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
> [mypath]\29595851800.ttf : Tenorite-Regular already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
> Found FontName for 0 fonts.
> Scanning afm files in C:/Users/[me]/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-lib/extrafontdb/metrics

Originally it seemed to add the font(s) to the database.

I then load the fonts.

```
loadfonts(device = "win")
```

and get output

> Tenorite already registered with windowsFonts().

When I run fonts() I get:

> [1] "Tenorite"

I then try to set the theme and plot something

```
theme_set(theme_bw(base_family = "Tenorite"))
plot = ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(6, 7, 8)))+
  aes(x = x, y = y)+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title = "TEST font!")

plot
```

which results in the following
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTCif.png). This looks no different from the base font. I am, however, able to change the font this way. If I then do

```
theme_set(theme_bw(base_family = "mono"))
plot
```

I get [the same plot with different font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGMH5.png). Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out why what I tried was not working, but using [showtext](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html) works perfectly.

```
library(showtext)
font_add(family = "Tenorite", regular = "C:/[path].ttf")
showtext_auto()
theme_set(theme_bw(base_family = "Tenorite", base_size = 18))

plot = ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(6, 7, 8)))+
  aes(x = x, y = y)+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title = "TEST font!")

plot
```

Gives me [image: this graph with the correct font!]